# Stopping the execution of R script until the data are avaiable

Tags: r, batch-file

I am trying to create two windows batch files in R and then run them one by one. These batch jobs would export data out of a database and the rest of the R script would format the exported data which then would be used for other purposes. The issue I am facing is that I created the batch files and then ran the jobs using the shell command. However these batch jobs take some time to complete. While they are still running, the rest of the script is executed and since it doesn't find the dataframes (which were supposed to be created as a result of batch job completion), it fails. Is there a way to specify in R that the script should not be executed until the batch jobs are done and the data are available. Since it takes a different amount of time to complete the job every time it runs, I don't want to use the Sleep command. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide all the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply checking every second if the file the batch produces already exists

```
while (!file.exists(destfile)) 
{
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

This way the execution stays in the while loop till the file is there.  (without needing much resources)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the while loop but it kept giving me an error that the destination file does not exist (although that was the whole point). However I read some more and found that if I just use "shell" instead of "shell.exe", the problem would be solved because "shell" by default has the option of wait=true (explained in one of the stackoverflow questions).